# search displaytemplate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search, display-template

I have the below code

```
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">
                <!--#_
                        var clickType = ctx.CurrentItem.csr_ClickType;
                        if(!clickType) {clickType = "Result";}
                        var appAttribs = "";
                        if (!$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_OpenApp)) { appAttribs += "openApp=\"" + $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_OpenApp) + "\""; };
                        if (!$isEmptyString(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_OpenControl)) { appAttribs += " openControl=\"" + $htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_OpenControl) + "\""; };

                        var taskContainerHyperlinkDescription = ctx.CurrentItem.HyperlinkDescription;
                        var taskContainerHyperlink = $htmlEncode($getItemValue(ctx, "Hyperlink"));
                        var taskContainerHyperlinkText;

                        if($isEmptyString(taskContainerHyperlinkDescription)) {
                            taskContainerHyperlinkText = $htmlEncode($resource("TaskContainerLinkString"));
                        } else {
                            taskContainerHyperlinkText = $htmlEncode(taskContainerHyperlinkDescription);
                        }
                        processHyperlink = String.format('<a clicktype="{0}" href="{1}" class="ms-srch-item-link" style="font-size:1.15em" title="{2}" onfocus="{3}" {4}>{5}</a>',
                                            $htmlEncode(clickType), $urlHtmlEncode(taskContainerHyperlink), taskContainerHyperlink,
                                            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback, appAttribs, taskContainerHyperlinkText );
                        var value = processHyperlink;

                _#-->
                _#= value =#_
            </td>
```

The description is not displaying the complete text if there is a comma in the text and cutting it and displaying the text after comma. am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the style to the HTML part, for example:

```
<a clicktype="" href="" class="ms-srch-item-link" style="font-size:1.15em">_#= Placeholder =#_</a>
```

After display the description. I'd see if there's still missing text after a comma.

Comment: If the style tag is seperated then how the style is applied to the text ?.

Comment: you can write css in the template or the main css file, and wrap it in  HTML tag like normal web front-end. Only the dynamic data is from SharePoint (the _#= placeholder =#_ part)